# Pulling capacity and slots left from entity registration

Tags: views, entities

I'd like to pull the values for capacity and the slots left from a registration created by the entity registration module. This sets up registration entities which are attached to (I believe this is how it works - my familiarity with the entity system is only so-so at this point, but I'm actively learning) nodes.

I'm creating a view for the event nodes, I would like to display these fields - how would I go about doing that? Would I create a relationship of some sort in the view?

What's the standard method to pull another, related entity's content into a node entity?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by pulling in the relationship of "Registration Settings: Node to Registration Settings" and putting the fields for total as well as used slots in.

In addition, when needing to calculate the amount of remaining slots, I calculated this with views php.

Comment: I am sorry for posting this as an answer but I am having a similar problem and I would really appreciate if you could elaborate a little on how exactly did you resolve your problem.

Comment: You have to create a relationship between Registration Settings and nodes.

You should then be able to pull the fields used for Registration Settings into your view.

When it came to the remaining slots, I just enabled the Views PHP module, and did a simple calculation between two variables.

Can you elaborate on your problem a little bit more?